# how to get which computer (IP and Name) accessed the file in Shared Folder in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

How to get which computer (IP and Name) accessed the file in Shared Folder in VB.Net, My code it should fetching my system IP address and system name while file accessed by another system, How to get which computer (IP and Name) accessed the file.

Monitor network shared folder

I am trying to monitor a network shared folder using FileSystemWatcher on Windows.

My code is below.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1

    Private watchers As New List(Of FileSystemWatcher)

    ' Dictionary to store last access times of files
    Private lastAccessTimes As New Dictionary(Of String, DateTime)

    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim flag As Integer = 0
    Dim qry As String

    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader

    Dim data As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;jet OLEDB:Database Password=open;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Database.accdb;"

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


        con.ConnectionString = data

        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.Open()
        End If

        load_file_path()

        monitoring_access()

    End Sub

    Private Sub load_file_path()

        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.Open()
        End If

        qry = "select * from Tbl_FilePath where Status=" & "'Active';"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(qry, con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If dr.HasRows Then
            While dr.Read
                DGView2.Rows.Add(dr("File_Path"))
                'Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(dr("File_Path"))
            End While
        End If

        con.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub img_settings_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles img_settings.Click
        Settings.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub monitoring_access()


        ' Start monitoring folders
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGView2.Rows
            Dim folderPath As String = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
            AddFolderToWatcher(folderPath)
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub AddFolderToWatcher(folderPath As String)

        If Directory.Exists(folderPath) Then

            ' Create a new instance of FileSystemWatcher for the specified path
            Dim watcher As New FileSystemWatcher(folderPath)

            AddHandler watcher.Created, AddressOf FileSystemWatcher_Event
            AddHandler watcher.Deleted, AddressOf FileSystemWatcher_Event
            AddHandler watcher.Changed, AddressOf FileSystemWatcher_Event
            AddHandler watcher.Renamed, AddressOf FileSystemWatcher_Event

            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = True
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True

            watchers.Add(watcher)

        Else
            MessageBox.Show($"Folder does not exist: {folderPath}")
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub FileSystemWatcher_Event(sender As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)
        ' Handle file system events here
        Dim eventType As String = GetEventType(e.ChangeType)

        Dim operation As String = $"{eventType}"

        'Dim username As String = currentIdentity.Name
        Dim username As String = $"{Environment.UserName}"
        'Dim user As String = GetUsername()
        Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim GetDateTime As String = now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
        Dim file_path As String = $"{e.FullPath}"

        'CheckAccessedUser(file_path)

        If Not file_path.Contains("$") Or file_path.Contains("@") Then
            ' The filePath does not contain '$'
            update_DGView1(operation, username, GetDateTime, file_path)
        End If

        'UpdateListBox(message)

        ' Update last access time in the dictionary
        lastAccessTimes(e.FullPath) = File.GetLastAccessTime(e.FullPath)

        ' Check if the file has been accessed (opened or viewed)
        Dim lastAccessTime As DateTime
        If lastAccessTimes.TryGetValue(e.FullPath, lastAccessTime) AndAlso
           File.GetLastAccessTime(e.FullPath) <> lastAccessTime Then
            'message += " - Viewed"
            update_DGView1("Viewed", username, GetDateTime, file_path)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Function GetEventType(changeType As WatcherChangeTypes) As String
        Select Case changeType
            Case WatcherChangeTypes.Created
                Return "Created"
            Case WatcherChangeTypes.Changed
                Return "Edited"
            Case WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted
                Return "Deleted"
            Case WatcherChangeTypes.Renamed
                Return "Renamed"
            Case Else
                Return "Unknown event"
        End Select

    End Function

    Private Sub update_DGView1(operation As String, user As String, GetDateTime As String, file_path As String)
        If DGView1.InvokeRequired Then
            DGView1.Invoke(Sub() update_DGView1(operation, user, GetDateTime, file_path))
        Else
            ' Your DGView1 update code goes here
            DGView1.Rows.Add(operation, user, GetDateTime, file_path)
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```